# More Fields Wordpress plugin - TinyMCE WYSIWYG JS error - can't add images

Tags: plugins, wordpress

For some reason, I am getting a JS error on the more fields WYSIWYG field.

When I try to click the button to add an image, or video...or audio, nothing happens and I get a JS error in the Firefox JS error console.

More fields version: 2.0.5
Wordpress version: 3.1

I am unable to downgrade wordpress any further due to potential problems with other plugins. I have tried different versions of more fields but I get the same issue.

Please help if you can, as I can't be the only one with this issue, it may be seriously helpful to others. it's a bit of a show stopper for me - my client ain't happy :-s

Please see the screenshot which might explain things a little more:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZSMb.jpg

Thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem just now.

Adding:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'wp_tiny_mce', 25);
```

To my functions.php file fixed it. I think the plugin fails to load this script by default.

Cheers